# Combining rows of a table using similar cells of one of its columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table (1) in Excel, with two columns, in which at the first column (A) there are some numbers and at the second column (B) there are some letters. I want to have a method to make another table (2) from (1) to put  different letters at the first column then to put in each row the numbers that were corresponded to letters in table (1).

For example, let the table (1) is:

```
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | b |
```

What is a method in Excel which make the following combination table:

```
| a | 1 | 2 |   |
| b | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| c | 2 |   |   |
```

in which letters are in first column and in each row there are the numbers that were in relationship with the row's letter in table (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per below screenshot use below formula to `C1` cell.

```
=UNIQUE(B1:B6)
```

And following formula to `D2` cell then drag down

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6=C1)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Do not you mean to add the second formula to D1?

Comment: @AmHsnSharafi Yes. You are correct!